# Why can't Julia parse functions parse numbers in scientific notation with d instead of e?

Tags: string, parsing, julia, numbers, scientific-notation

I am writing a program where I need to parse numbers written in scientific notation (as 0.00812216d0) from a file. It turns out that Julia parse(Type,str) can't parse these numbers because of 'd'.

It works well if I swap 'd' with 'e'. However, it's very unpractical to write replace function everywhere. I can't just do it for the whole text file, as it would cause some unwanted changes. Any solution?

Comment: `parse(Type, replace(str, 'd' => 'e'))`. Why is this impractical? What is everywhere? Repeated work should go in a function.

Comment: Side remark for anyone else who hasn't come across this notation: according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Examples_and_other_notations), the `d` stands for "decapower", and among major languages, Matlab and Fortran are the ones that understand this notation: Matlab treats them the same, while Fortran treats e-notation as single precision and d-notation as indicating double precision.

Comment: Occasionally, [Parsers.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/Parsers.jl) can't parse strings with d-notation of exponent too. @BallpointBen's answer seems OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try (if you want double precision, ie 64 bit floats):

```
dparse(s) = parse(Float64, replace(s, 'd' => 'e'))
```

as BallpontBen said in comments. For BigFloat, replace 'Float64' with BigFloat above. If you get errors from your data parsing, consider

```
dparse(s) = something(tryparse(Float64, replace(s, 'd' => 's')), missing)
```

which will give you missing for parse errors instead of throwing an error.